# Laravel 5 displaying an Array of Objects returned from Parse.com

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I am trying to pass an array of objects to the view and then use the blade templating engine to loop through them.

The data is being returned from a Parse.com query and is structured like this:

```
[
    {
        "Params": [],
        "difficulty": "Medium",
        "exerciseDescription": "Sit on a gym ball with a dumbbell in each hand. Bend your elbows to lift the dumbbells to your shoulder.",
        "exerciseID": "1024",
        "exerciseName": "Bicep Curl Sitting on Gym Ball",
        "images": [
            2758,
            2759,
            2760
        ],
        "objectId": "9xjQ4WVo6e",
        "tags": [
            "Dumbbell",
            "Gym Ball",
            "Flexion"
        ],
        "words": [
            "seated",
            "dumbbell",
            "arm",
            "curl"
        ]
    }
]
```

I am getting this using this query:

```
public function about()
    {

      $programmeId = 'T8iqZhtDqe';
      $query = new ParseQuery("PrescribedProgrammes");
            try {
              $programme = $query->get($programmeId);
              // The object was retrieved successfully.
            } catch (ParseException $ex) {
                echo $ex;
              // The object was not retrieved successfully.
              // error is a ParseException with an error code and message.
            }

        $exerciseData = $programme->get("exerciseData");
        $programmeTitle = $programme->get("prescribedProgrammeTitle");


        // return view('pages.about', compact('exerciseData','programmeTitle'));

        return view('pages.about')->with('exerciseData', $exerciseData);

    }
```

And to test this I have been trying:

```
@foreach($exerciseData as $exercise => $value)
    {{ $exercise->exerciseName }}
@endforeach
```

However I am getting a `Array to string conversion` error. Coming from a angularJS background I am hoping to pass my array of objects to the view and then loop through them as I see fit. 
Would this be considered poor form?

EDIT

Running `dd($exerciseData)`

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => array:9 [▼
    "Params" => []
    "difficulty" => "Medium"
    "exerciseDescription" => "Sit on a gym ball with a dumbbell in each hand. Bend your elbows to lift the dumbbells to your shoulder."
    "exerciseID" => "1024"
    "exerciseName" => "Bicep Curl Sitting on Gym Ball"
    "images" => array:6 [▶]
    "objectId" => "9xjQ4WVo6e"
    "tags" => array:6 [▶]
    "words" => array:8 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:9 [▶]
  2 => array:9 [▶]
  3 => array:9 [▶]
  4 => array:9 [▶]
  5 => array:9 [▶]
  6 => array:9 [▶]
]
```

Comment: No, I would not consider that poor form. From a program architecture standpoint, you might consider putting the loop guts inside a *partial*, so that the business of looping remains separate from the business of displaying a looped item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the key of the array instead of the value. For example the default PHP foreach looks like the following:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    // code
}
```

Edit: 
After looking at the dump of $exerciseData it appears that PHP is serializing the JSON into an array, so this changes the answer.

If you return this to the view:

```
return view('quiz.create', compact('programmeTitle', 'exerciseData'));
```

Then have the following in your view it should work as I have tested it locally:

```
<h2>{{$programmeTitle}}</h2>
@foreach ($exerciseData as $key => $exercise)
    <p>{{$exercise['exerciseName']}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Array to string conversion (View: /Users/myusername/Sites/PHP/mayappl/test-Guru/resources/views/pages/about.blade.php)` when trying to use `return view('pages.about', compact('exerciseData'));`

Comment: Can you `dd($exerciseData);` so we can see the structure of that variable?

Comment: I've added this to my post

Comment: Ok and what is the structure you are trying to achieve, am I right in thinking it would be adding the $programmeTitle to each $excerciseData object?

Without the extra $programmeTitle stuff it should work with this:
    `return view('pages.about')->with('exerciseData', $exerciseData);` and 
    `@foreach($exerciseData as $key => $exercise)
        {{ $exercise->exerciseName }}
    @endforeach`

Comment: Sorry I meant the object structure! Where is it that you need `$programmeTitle` to be?

Comment: The title of the page will be `$programmeTitle` and then the `$exerciseData` will be looped under it.

Comment: I've edited my answer above, it should work as I've tested it but let me know.

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for spending the time on this. I'm getting this error http://imgur.com/IDRtx78

Comment: No problem, can you show me what's happening on line 6 of the view, the cached version should be located in `storage > framework > views > file ending in 52d`

Comment: Ohh... I delete that file in `storage > framework > views > file ending in 52d` and it now works perfectly... ? Whats the score with that??

Comment: That's good to hear at least! It could be that the about.blade.php didn't have it's timestamps updated upon saving, sometimes an issue with virtual machines, or potentially op code caching if you have that enabled?